# Free country/city suggestion list/database

Tags: jquery, geolocation, autosuggest

I'm looking for something similar to facebook suggestion list with
cities and countries.
You can see what I'm exactly talking about when you try to create new
event in facebook, click to add address, and then start typing in the
City field.

I prefer finding working suggestion tool in jQuery(with the date),
but database with city/country will do the trick too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/worldcities/

That's the database. It should be possible to work this into a jQuery tool pretty easily with (for example) one of the "autocomplete" plugins. It certainly should be easier than researching and constructing the database yourself :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Pointy, It looks just like what I was looking for.
What "Region" means?

Comment: Looks like "region" depends on what country it is; in the US, it's "state". In other countries it looks like it might be a postal code.

Comment: If someone else download this dump, be careful cause it contains duplicate cities with different spelling.

Comment: that database file is pretty big which is around 100 MB. Do you really dump it to your database ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes, I really dump it (using big dump)

Comment: Indeed. I thought it was worth highlighting anyway ;)

Answer (score 5):

http://www.geonames.org/

Comment: Yes, i think this is the best one. They have really good archive. Download list here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Answer (score 2):

[Freebase Suggest](http://www.freebase.com/docs/suggest) is a jQuery plug-in that does autocompletion against any of its set of categories.  You can easily limit it to countries (`"type": ["/location/country"]`) or cities, and it provides a nice UI for your users to verify that they're talking about the right place.

This way you don't have to manage the database, keep it up to date, build your own UI, etc.

Answer (score 0):

here is demo search of a weather forecast provider:
http://www.wunderground.com/

their API provides much simpler and more accurate data set regarding city/country lookup:
http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/documentation.html#auto

Answer (score 0):

depending on your application, you might consider using Google Maps API autocomplete.

http://code.google.com/intl/sk-SK/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#places_autocomplete

Please understand that there commercial restrictions may apply to the use of GMA (free vs business) and its functions.  Check out the terms of use before deciding for the use of GMA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cities/countries database in Microsoft SQL / Mysql Format** from here -

http://myip.ms/info/cities_sql_database/World_Cities_SQL_Mysql_Database.html

Cities/Countries Table structure is -

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
  cityID int NOT NULL,
  cityName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  stateID int NOT NULL,
  countryID varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  latitude float NOT NULL,
  longitude float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cityID),
  UNIQUE (countryID,stateID,cityID)
);

CREATE TABLE countries (
  countryID varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  countryName varchar(52) NOT NULL,
  localName varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  webCode varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  region varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  continent varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  latitude float NOT NULL,
  longitude float NOT NULL,
  surfaceArea float NOT NULL,
  population int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (countryID),
  UNIQUE (webCode),
  UNIQUE (countryName)
);
```